# Flask request object always empty (GET and POST)

Tags: python, postgresql, post, flask, request

this is the code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request, redirect, url_for, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://postgres:root@localhost/gradelink'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Location(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'location'
    id = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    location_name = db.Column('location_name', db.String(250), unique=True)

    def __init__(self, location_name):
        self.location_name = location_name
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Location %r' % self.location_name

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('home.html');

@app.route('/location', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def location():
    return render_template('location.html');
    
@app.route('/post_location', methods=['POST'])
def post_location():
    if request.method == "POST":
        location_n = request.form['location_name']
        
    return redirect(url_for('index'))

@app.route('/location_list', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def location_list():
    locationList = Location.query.all()
    return render_template('location_list.html', locationList=locationList);

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I tried with both, GET and POST but still, same result:

## object has no attribute 'data'

## object has no attribute 'form'

**location_list works perfectly.**

looks like the request is always empty

my submission form html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Location Form</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="/post_location">
    <label>Location name:</label>
    <input id="location_name" name="location_name" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT 1:

I tried this:

```
@app.route('/post_location', methods=['POST'])
def post_location():
    if request.method == "POST":
        location_n = request.form['location_name']
        
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

now the error message is:

## 'function' object has no attribute 'method'

EDIT 2:

I don't have a function called `request` and I don't have many other functions (this is a new fresh project)

No I don't have any `flask.py` files in any of my project folders.

EDIT 3: Flask and Python versions

```
C:\Users\Daniel>flask --version
Flask 1.0.2
Python 3.7.1 (v3.7.1:260ec2c36a, Oct 20 2018, 14:57:15) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

Traceback

```
builtins.AttributeError
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'method'

Traceback (most recent call last)
File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2309, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "C:\myproject\flask\__init__.py", line 89, in post_location
if request.method == "POST":
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'method'
```

Comment: Do you have a function called `request` defined somewhere? Do you have a file in your path that happens to be called `flask.py`? How are you initializing and running the Flask App? Do. You know how to run your code in debug mode? Do that and inspect what `request` actually is, because it sounds like it's not actually the `request` proxy from Flask.

Comment: Perhaps it would help to post your full code.

Comment: I added the full code to the question, how can I inspect the request? the code is in debug already

Comment: I admit I can't see anything imm wrong with the code. How do you run it? How are the errors reported? Do you get a traceback? Does the Flask server start at all?

Comment: Oh, tho in your HTML do write method="post" in lowercase.

Comment: Please also make sure you're using a recent version of Flask.

Comment: I've added flask/python versions and the Traceback

Comment: But how do you start the app? I assume the exception occurs when you submit the form?

Comment: (Wish I could be more helpful, but I've done plenty of Flask and SQLAlchemy and never seen anything quite like this. It's definitely not obvious. If I have time tomorrow I'll try it myself and see.)

Comment: I run the server with Python __init__.py and everything works fine. But when I fill the input with the location name and hit submit it send me to /post_location and gives me the error saying that request doesn't have any attributes

Comment: That doesn't really answer anything. Please post the exact command that you run.

Comment: Sorry, it's my first Python project so I don't know what do you mean by run it... I open my CMD on Windows, activate flask on my project, then using the command "Python" I execute the file init.py. then I go to my localhost and everything is working fine but the posts and gets are not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183369/discussion-between-daniel-boldrin-and-iguananaut).

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up closing everything, restarting my computer and python. I received a different error (some lines had spaces instead of TAB for indentation) but easily fixed and then everything worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

Before your locationName, put in `if request.method == POST:` Then tab everything over underneath.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it didn't work (take a look at my edit1)